# insert only time in oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

how to insert only time in hh:mi in oracle and how to run select query by comparing time.

Explanation:
 Let consider a doctor visit in hospital daily from 9AM to 11AM and 6PM to 8PM.
SO when we run a select query to search doctors who visit at 10AM on particular day.

Please give explanation with code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a poor question, you should try to solve it yourself before asking here. Once you have tried, post your attempts and any error messages you received and you will get some help.

Comment: You want to consider time only, yet you also state you want to "search doctors who visit at 10AM *on particular day*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need basic date arithmetic, and the plain old date type.

```
CREATE TABLE doctor_visits (
    doctor_id    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    in_time      DATE NOT NULL,
    out_time     DATE NOT NULL
)
/
```

I presume you want to find doctors who were in the hospital at 10:00am, as opposed to doctors who visited exactly at 10AM

```
SELECT doctor_id FROM doctor_visits 
where in_time < trunc(in_time) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(10,'HOUR') 
AND out_time > trunc(in_time) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(10,'HOUR') ;
```

I haven't considered the use case where in_time and out_time fall on different dates, i.e. say 11:00PM in and 2:00 am out.

OR IF you want to find a list of Doctors who visited the hospital exactly at 10:00AM then

```
SELECT doctor_id FROM doctor_visits where to_char(in_time,'HH:MI') = '10:00' ;
```

But that would be a very strange thing to query, as you really can't be sure if some one visits exactly at that specific time.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question.I was confused what to use.That is Date datatype or number datatype.I want a list of doctors between in_time and out_time.